# VHDL testbench for dflipflop

Tags: vhdl

i am new to vhdl, i have been trying to write testbench for d-flipflop and a buffer which allows me to write my output of dflipflop on a tester depending on buffer ,but i am unable to change the values of inputs in the testbench can you please help me out. This is my code for vhdl and testbench for it..

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
entity Dflipflop1 is 
   port
  ( D0_in,EN_low,in4 :in std_logic;
     q :out std_logic
  );
end entity Dflipflop1;
architecture Dff of Dflipflop1 is 
begin 
 process(D0_in,EN_low,in4)
begin 
 if (in4 = '1' and EN_low = '0') then 
        q <= D0_in;
else
   q <= '0';
end if ;
    end process;
end architecture Dff;

library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity tribuffer1 is 
   port
  ( in1_b,in2_b :in std_logic;
     out_b :out std_logic
  );
end entity tribuffer1;

architecture tbf of tribuffer1 is 
begin 
 process(in1_b,in2_b)
begin 
 if (in1_b = '0') then 
   out_b <= in2_b;
else 
   out_b <= 'Z';
end if ;
end process;
 end architecture tbf;


library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity pin11 is
port 
(
RD,RESET,EN_low,WR,CS5A,CS6A,CS7A,D7_in,D6_in,D5_in,D4_in,D3_in,D2_in,D1_in,D0_in: in std_logic;
D0_out,D1_out,D2_out,D3_out,D4_out,D5_out,D6_out,D7_out: out std_logic
--P0,P1,P2,P3,P4,P5: out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0)
);
end entity pin11;

architecture logic of pin11 is
 component Dflipflop1 is 
  port
  ( D0_in,EN_low,in4 :in std_logic;
     q :out std_logic
  );
 end component;
 component tribuffer1 is 
  port   
   ( in1_b,in2_b : in std_logic;
     out_b :out std_logic
   );
 end component;

signal Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5,Q6,Q7,Q8,Q9,Q10,Q11,Q12,Q13,Q14,Q15,Q16,Q17,Q18 : std_logic;

begin
D1 : Dflipflop1 port map(RD,EN_low,'1',Q1);
D2 : Dflipflop1 port map(WR,En_low,'1',Q4);
-----D0 pin------------
D0_R : Dflipflop1 port map(D0_in,EN_low,RESET,Q2);
B0_R : tribuffer1 port map(Q1,Q2,D0_out);
---- D1 pin--------
D1_R : Dflipflop1 port map(D1_in,EN_low,RESET,Q5);
B1_R : tribuffer1 port map(Q1,Q5,D1_out);
---- D2 pin--------
D2_R : Dflipflop1 port map(D2_in,EN_low,RESET,Q7);
B2_R : tribuffer1 port map(Q1,Q7,D2_out);
---- D3 pin--------
D3_R : Dflipflop1 port map(D3_in,EN_low,RESET,Q9);
B3_R : tribuffer1 port map(Q1,Q9,D3_out);
---- D4 pin--------
D4_R : Dflipflop1 port map (D4_in,EN_low,RESET,Q11);
B4_R : tribuffer1 port map(Q1,Q11,D4_out);
---- D5 pin--------
D5_R : Dflipflop1 port map(D5_in,EN_low,RESET,Q13);
B5_R : tribuffer1 port map(Q1,Q13,D5_out);
---- D6 pin--------
D6_R : Dflipflop1 port map(D6_in,EN_low,RESET,Q15);
B6_R : tribuffer1 port map(Q1,Q15,D6_out);
---- D7 pin--------
D7_R : Dflipflop1 port map(D7_in,EN_low,RESET,Q17);
B7_R : tribuffer1 port map(Q1,Q17,D7_out);
end architecture logic;

architecture logic of pin11 is
 component Dflipflop1 is 
  port
  ( D0_in,EN_low,in4 :in std_logic;
     q :out std_logic
  );
 end component;
 component tribuffer1 is 
  port   
   ( in1_b,in2_b : in std_logic;
     out_b :out std_logic
   );
 end component;

signal Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5,Q6,Q7,Q8,Q9,Q10,Q11,Q12,Q13,Q14,Q15,Q16,Q17,Q18 : std_logic;

begin
D1 : Dflipflop1 port map(RD,EN_low,'1',Q1);
D2 : Dflipflop1 port map(WR,En_low,'1',Q4);
-----D0 pin------------
D0_R : Dflipflop1 port map(D0_in,EN_low,RESET,Q2);
B0_R : tribuffer1 port map(Q1,Q2,D0_out);
---- D1 pin--------
D1_R : Dflipflop1 port map(D1_in,EN_low,RESET,Q5);
B1_R : tribuffer1 port map(Q1,Q5,D1_out);
---- D2 pin--------
D2_R : Dflipflop1 port map(D2_in,EN_low,RESET,Q7);
B2_R : tribuffer1 port map(Q1,Q7,D2_out);
---- D3 pin--------
D3_R : Dflipflop1 port map(D3_in,EN_low,RESET,Q9);
B3_R : tribuffer1 port map(Q1,Q9,D3_out);
---- D4 pin--------
D4_R : Dflipflop1 port map (D4_in,EN_low,RESET,Q11);
B4_R : tribuffer1 port map(Q1,Q11,D4_out);
---- D5 pin--------
D5_R : Dflipflop1 port map(D5_in,EN_low,RESET,Q13);
B5_R : tribuffer1 port map(Q1,Q13,D5_out);
---- D6 pin--------
D6_R : Dflipflop1 port map(D6_in,EN_low,RESET,Q15);
B6_R : tribuffer1 port map(Q1,Q15,D6_out);
---- D7 pin--------
D7_R : Dflipflop1 port map(D7_in,EN_low,RESET,Q17);
B7_R : tribuffer1 port map(Q1,Q17,D7_out);
end architecture logic;
```

**this is the testbench**

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;

--- entity declaration for your testbench.
ENTITY test_bench1 IS 
END test_bench1;

ARCHITECTURE logic OF test_bench1 IS
   -- Component Declaration for the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    component pin11  --'test' is the name of the module needed to be tested.
--just copy and paste the input and output ports of your module as such. 
  port 
(
RD,RESET,EN_low,WR,CS5A,CS6A,CS7A,D7_in,D6_in,D5_in,D4_in,D3_in,D2_in,D1_in,D0_in: in std_logic;
D0_out,D1_out,D2_out,D3_out,D4_out,D5_out,D6_out,D7_out: out std_logic
--P0,P1,P2,P3,P4,P5: out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0)
);
end component;

    signal RD,RESET,EN_low,WR,CS5A,CS6A,CS7A,D7_in,D6_in,D5_in,D4_in,D3_in,D2_in,D1_in,D0_in,D0_out,D1_out,D2_out,D3_out,D4_out,D5_out,D6_out,D7_out: std_logic;
  -- signal  P0,P1,P2,P3,P4,P5:  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
begin
  mapping : pin11 port map(RD,RESET,EN_low,WR,CS5A,CS6A,CS7A,D7_in,D6_in,D5_in,D4_in,D3_in,D2_in,D1_in,D0_in,D0_out,D1_out,D2_out,D3_out,D4_out,D5_out,D6_out,D7_out);--,P0,P1,P2,P3,P4,P5);
   test:process
  variable errCnt : integer := 0;
begin
  CS5A <= '0';
  CS6A <= '0';
  CS7A <= '0';
  RD <= '0';
  RESET <= '1';
  EN_low <= '0';
  --CLK <= '0';
  WR <= '1';
  D0_in <= '0';
  D1_in <= '1';
  D2_in <= '1';
  D3_in <= '0';
  D4_in <= '1';
  D5_in <= '0';
  D6_in <= '1';
  D7_in <= '0';

  wait for 5 ns;

     assert( D1_out = '1') report "Cout error 3" severity error;
     if(D0_out /= '1') then
         errCnt := errCnt + 1;
     end if;
  D4_in <= '0';
  D5_in <= '1';
  D6_in <= '0';
  D7_in <= '1';
 if(errCnt = 0) then
       assert false report "Success!" severity note;
     else
        assert false report "Failure!" severity note;
     end if;
wait;
 end process;
end logic;
```

My input values are always 01010110(D7_in to D0_in)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will never see the second set of values on `D4_in` to `D7_in`, because your simulation stops immediately after having driven the new values on these signals. How about adding a `wait for 5 ns;` (or similar) somewhere between this line:

```
  D7_in <= '1';
```

and this line:

```
wait;
```